# git insufficient permission for adding an object to local git server repository

Tags: php, git, apache, shell, ssh

I have an `www-data` running with `php` which is controlling a git server.
The `www-data` user creates Unix users (having given it `sudo adduser`), and those users are supposed to control their own private git directory, where each user can house his/hers repositories.

I've followed [this guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) at least ten times, in addition to which, I'm also [following this guide](http://planzero.org/blog/2012/10/24/hosting_an_admin-friendly_git_server_with_git-shell) in order to create the git server.

- Apache adds a **unix user** `bar`, with a home in `/var/www/git/bar` and the user has no password (`--disable-password`)
- The user `bar` is part of group `gitusers` which allows `+rwx` to the group members, and has his shell set to `/usr/bin/git-shell`.
- This is done so that `www-data` can access his home directory and populate it with repositories and ssh keys.
- The skeleton home directory is also populated with `git-shell-commands` and the user `www-data` creates an `/var/www/git/bar/.ssh/authorized_keys` where it appends my **test user's** `foo` **public key**.

When `www-data` adds a new user and then a new repository it does:

```
sudo adduser --disabled password\
             --home /var/www/git/bar\
             --conf /var/www/conf/adduser.conf\
             --ingroup gitusers\
             bar
```

The above ^^ is done via php.
The `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` are owned by `www-data`.

Then `www-data` proceeds to create a new directory and initialize it:

- `mkdir /var/www/git/bar/test.git`
- `cd /var/www/git/bar/test`
- `git --bare init`

My test user `foo` can read it from ssh (it just clones an empty repository).
Once I try to push an initial commit:

```
git clone ssh://foo@localhost:/var/www/git/bar/test.git
cd test
touch readme
vim readme
git add .
git commit -m "init"
git push origin master
foo@127.0.0.1's password:
Counting objects: 6, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 411 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://foo@localhost:/var/www/git/bar/random.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://foo@localhost:/var/www/git/bar/random.git'
```

I am asked for `foo` user's password (which is the user with the public key).

This is NOT the Unix user who owns the home directory, that is user `bar` who has a disabled password.

1. why am I being asked for an ssh password? shouldn't they ssh key take care of that?
2. If I create a `bar` **with** a password, then I can use that git repository, replacing `foo@localhost:/var/www/git/bar` with `bar@localhost:/var/www/git/bar`
3. When I don't use `ssh://` at all, I am still able to `clone` but get the same error when pushing as`foo` but not as `bar` provided I enable the password.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Is it because the permissions of `.ssh` and `authorized_keys` are too open or not owned by `bar`?

Even when I go (as sudo) into the `bar` homedir and make everything owned by him, I still get the same error.

Finally, I have set my `.ssh/config` for test user `foo` so that:

```
Host localhost
     Hostname 127.0.0.1
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo
     User foo
```

Comment: While it's not an answer to your question, I think you attack this the wrong way. Look at gitolite and if that (nor gitlab) don't fit your needs, look at how they implement letting users have private repositories.

It's a much easier solution to have one git user for all users. Many unix users is hard to succeed with in a good way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out it was indeed the permissions.
tailing the `/var/log/auth.log` provided the insight:

`Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /var/www/git/bar`

Googling this I figured out the problem was that the entire home directory was accessible by the group.

So back to square one, allowing `www-data` to be part of the group with `+rwx` is not a possibility, since it breaks ssh.

## EDIT:

The comment from `iveqy` was very wise, using unix users for this sort of operation is an overkill and opens potential security holes, since it requires that you escalate user `www-data` to a superuser.

I've ended up using `gitolite-admin` the following way (I am adding it for future reference on how `www-data` the apache user under Debian/Ubuntu can control gitolite).

## Instructions

The webserver apache2 runs as `www-data` on the system.
All php scripts are executed as `www-data`.
This requires that we enable this user to administrate our git server automatically.

For `gitolite` to work, it requires that the administrator provides an ssh key.
This in turn requires that user `www-data` (apache2) has a pair of ssh keys.
The key pair **must be protected** else ssh won't work:

- create a new user `git` with home directory in: `/var/www/git`
- `sudo adduser git --home /var/www/git`
- cd into `/var/dir/git` and remove all skeleton files (.bashrc, .profile, .bash_logout)
- log **locally** as user git: `su - git` and use the password you created earlier
- make sure permissions of git user home dir are set to `755` (g+rx)
- create the `.ssh` dir: `mkdir .ssh` and then make it private: `chmod 700 -R .ssh`

Now as `www-data` create your ssh key (exit from `git` user):

- go into `/var/www/` and create an `./ssh` owned by www-data and with `700` mask.
- `sudo -u www-data ssh-keygen -t rsa`

If everything went accordingly, copy your `/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into `/var/www/git/.ssh/`

- give ownership of key to user `git`: `sudo chown git.git .ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- log back in as `git`: `su - git`
- make the pub key private: `chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Time to install `gitolite`:

- `git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite`
- `mkdir -p $HOME/bin`
- `gitolite/install -to $HOME/bin`

Setup the `www-data` public rsa key to be used as the administrator of gitolite:

- `$HOME/bin/gitolite setup -pk .ssh/id_rsa.pub`

You should get:

`Initialised empty Git repository in /var/www/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git/
Initialised empty Git repository in /var/www/git/repositories/testing.git/
WARNING: /var/www/git/.ssh/authorized_keys missing; creating a new one
    (this is normal on a brand new install)`

the user `git` is now setup.
logout: `exit`

**DO NOT TOUCH THE DIRECTORY /var/www/git FROM NOW ON**

We will clone it locally, and control it from there.
Clone it as user `www-data`:

- first create the local copy owned by `www-data`: `sudo mkdir gitolite-admin && chown -R www-data.www-data gitolite-admin/`
- then execute as user `www-data` the command: `sudo -u www-data git clone git@localhost:gitolite-admin gitolite-admin/`

This clones the `gitolite-admin` in `/var/www/gitolite-admin` from which you control the gitolite server.

For instructions on how to control the gitolite-server, see: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite

From now on, any gitolite command you execute, execute it as user `www-data`.
Any command run as `root` or with `sudo` will break the server!

#### PS: I accept no responsibility if this breaks your apache configuration. I hope it helps anyone coming here for the same reason I did: creating a git server. I'm open to suggestions and better ideas or improvements.